# I can't put function result on a window on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

So right now i am making a news API and I would like the result of

```py
filtrer_par_source(self.SourceBox)
```

print in my tkinter blue windows,
Code :

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import requests
from tkinter import *

class App:
     
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.SourceBox = None 
        #titre
        root.title("Tkinter News")
        #window size
        width=800
        height=500
        screenwidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenheight = root.winfo_screenheight()
        alignstr = '%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, (screenwidth - width) / 2, (screenheight - height) / 2)
        root.geometry(alignstr)
        root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        
        def Source_textbox_input(self):
            self.SourceBox=GLineEdit_166.get("1.0","end-1c")
        
        ### BUTTON LABEL TEXTBOX ###
        GLineEdit_166=tk.Text(root)
        GLineEdit_166["borderwidth"] = "1px"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GLineEdit_166["font"] = ft
        GLineEdit_166["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLineEdit_166.place(x=150,y=140,width=88,height=30)
        
        GLabel_708=tk.Label(root)
        GLabel_708["bg"] = "#eedbff"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=15)
        GLabel_708["font"] = ft
        GLabel_708["fg"] = "#333333"
        GLabel_708["justify"] = "center"
        GLabel_708["text"] = "Source"
        GLabel_708.place(x=20,y=140,width=120,height=30)
        
        GButton_491=tk.Button(root)
        GButton_491["bg"] = "#eedbff"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GButton_491["font"] = ft
        GButton_491["fg"] = "#000000"
        GButton_491["justify"] = "center"
        GButton_491["text"] = "Valider"
        GButton_491.place(x=250,y=140,width=68,height=30)
        GButton_491["command"] = lambda: Source_textbox_input(self)

        GButton_412=tk.Button(root)
        GButton_412["bg"] = "#eedbff"
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=10)
        GButton_412["font"] = ft
        GButton_412["fg"] = "#000000"
        GButton_412["justify"] = "center"
        GButton_412["text"] = "Write"
        GButton_412.place(x=322,y=140,width=68,height=30)
        GButton_412["command"] = self.GButton_412_command
        ### ----------------- ###
        

    def GButton_412_command(self):
        print("afficher source")
        def filtrer_par_source(nom): #FILTER FOR SOURCE
            """
            fonction qui filtre les recherches selon la source choisis
            """
            rien = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=,&br&apiKey=67d4540bfb764bc69b76e6f65298ab1f')
            listeurl = rien.split(',')
            #print(listeurl)
            url = str(listeurl[0] + nom + listeurl[1])
            #print(url)
            
            rep = requests.get(url)
            print(rep.json())
        
        #filtrer_par_source(self.SourceBox)   
        
##### Create a windows for the function result on Tkinter ####
        GMessage_942=tk.Message(root)
        ft = tkFont.Font(family='Times',size=9)
        GMessage_942["bg"] = "#afdbff"
        GMessage_942["font"] = ft
        GMessage_942["fg"] = "#333333"
        GMessage_942["justify"] = "center"
        GMessage_942["text"] = filtrer_par_source(self.SourceBox)
        GMessage_942.place(x=420,y=110,width=370,height=360)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

So I think that

```py
GMessage_942["text"] = filtrer_par_source(self.SourceBox)
```

is not the best way to do it
I think I heard about output
But I don't know how it's work, help

I tried to use `tk.Message`, then import with ["text"] = the function

Comment: `filtrer_par_source()` returns `None`.  You need to change it to return what you want. Also `tk.Message` is obsolete, use `tk.Label` instead.

Comment: FYI: You should remove `from tkinter import *` - you don't need it if you already have `import tkinter as tk`, and [star imports are a bad idea](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-import-star-in-python-is-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what value(s) you want to pass to your label's text (and yes, @acw1668 is right, you should be using a `tk.Label` instead of `tk.Message`), but since you're printing the JSON data inside `filtrer_par_source()`, I've modified the function to ***return*** that data instead of just calling `print()`

```
def GButton_412_command(self):
    print("afficher source")
    def filtrer_par_source(nom): #FILTER FOR SOURCE
        """
        fonction qui filtre les recherches selon la source choisis
        """
        rien = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=,&br&apiKey=67d4540bfb764bc69b76e6f65298ab1f')
        listeurl = rien.split(',')
        #print(listeurl)
        url = str(listeurl[0] + nom + listeurl[1])
        #print(url)
            
        rep = requests.get(url)
        return rep.json()  # change 'print()' to 'return'
```

Now when you assign the result of the function to a variable like this...

```
GMessage_942["text"] = filtrer_par_source(self.SourceBox)
```

`GMessage_942`'s `text` will be set to the JSON data instead of `None`

Comment: Thank you so much, 
I use tk.Message, cause tk,Label write everyting in one line
But now I have another problem..
some texte are cut, is it possible to make like a scroll bar ?

Comment: You could try the `ScrolledText` widget instead of a `Message`/`Label` - [see docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html). To use it, just `from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText` and instantiate it like you would any other widget. (and FYI, you can insert newline characters `'\n'` into strings to split them up for a `Label`.) Hope that helps!

Comment: So i replace  GMessage_942=tk.Message(root) by 
GMessage_942=tk.ScrolledText(root) ?

It says module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'ScrolledText'

Comment: You have to import it separately like I described, then you can instantiate it a la `GMessage_942=ScrolledText(root)`. You can update its contents via `GMessage_942.insert(tk.INSERT, 'your text here')` then make it "read only" by setting its state to 'disabled': `GMessage_942.config(state='disabled')` (this will, however, prevent selection and copy/paste). [This tutorial](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-scrolledtext/) might help.

Comment: `GMessage_942=tk.ScrolledText(root)` then `GMessage_942.insert(tk.INSERT, 'your text here')`  then `GMessage_942.config(state='disabled')`




Like this ?

Comment: Pretty much. Just replace `GMessage_942=tk.Message(root)` - you may also have to tweak the call to `place()` to get the sizing you want. Personally I prefer to use `pack()` instead, but either will work

Comment: what in the  `'your text here'` , oh and it still says `AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'ScrolledText'`

Comment: `'your text here'` should be replaced with the value you want to display, i.e. the value returned by `filtrer_par_source(self.SourceBox)`. And if you're still getting that error, your import statement is probably wrong. *Again*: **You have to import it separately like I described** `from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText`

Comment: I did `from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText` but it still saying me this

Comment: Ah, I'm guessing you're instantiating it as `tk.ScrolledText` - you don't need the `tk.` namespace prefix here since you imported it directly. You should just use `ScrolledText` as-is! (I know it's a bit confusing - no worries)